# Plotly Bubble map bubbles not displaying

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, geospatial

Currently working with a US Cities dataset for some further analysis in a Jupyter Notebook project. Still an amateur in Python DS, want to make an interactive bubble map with plotly, displaying population per US city. Provided output of Code in photo. Structure of DataFrame:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 19500 entries, 0 to 19499
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column                Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                --------------  -----  
 0   US Pop Rank           19500 non-null  int64  
 1   City                  19500 non-null  object 
 2   State                 19500 non-null  object 
 3   2019 Population       19500 non-null  int64  
 4   Pop Growth 2000-2019  19383 non-null  object 
 5   Longitude             19500 non-null  float64
 6   Latitude              19500 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(3)
memory usage: 1.2+ MB
```

And the following code for the plot:

```
Geographics['text'] = Geographics['City'] + '<br>Population ' + (Geographics['2019 Population']/1e6).astype(str)+' million'
limits = [(0,2),(3,10),(11,20),(21,50),(50,3000)]
colors = ["royalblue","crimson","lightseagreen","orange","lightgrey"]
cities = []
scale = 5000

fig = go.Figure()

for i in range(len(limits)):
    lim = limits[i]
    Geographics_sub = Geographics[lim[0]:lim[1]]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = Geographics_sub['Longitude'],
        lat = Geographics_sub['Latitude'],
        text = Geographics_sub['text'],
        marker = dict(
            size = Geographics_sub['2019 Population']/scale,
            color = colors[i],
            line_color = 'rgb(40,40,40)',
            line_width = 0.5,
            sizemode = 'area'
        ),
        name = '{0} - {1}'.format(lim[0],lim[1])))

fig.update_layout(
        title_text = '2019 US city populations<br>(Click legend to toggle traces)',
        showlegend = True,
        geo = dict(
            scope = 'usa',
            landcolor = 'rgb(219, 219, 219)',
        )
    )

fig.show()
```

[Map Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsp3J.png3)

Comment: What import are you using for all of the `go.` functions?

Comment: plotly.graph_objects

Comment: Is the state name of the data used a proper name or a shortened name? Can you provide reproducible data, or if on the web, linked data?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, here is the raw data and the github posting:  https://github.com/matteo-psnt/Us-Cities-Population-and-Geographic-coordinates/blob/main/Cities%20By%20Population%20and%20Geographic%20coordinates%20-%20city_info.csv

Answer (score 0):

Order can matter, try swapping these sections of code as you may have the map on top of the scatters.

```
Geographics['text'] = Geographics['City'] + '<br>Population ' + (Geographics['2019 Population']/1e6).astype(str)+' million'
limits = [(0,2),(3,10),(11,20),(21,50),(50,3000)]
colors = ["royalblue","crimson","lightseagreen","orange","lightgrey"]
cities = []
scale = 5000

fig = go.Figure()

fig.update_layout(
        title_text = '2019 US city populations<br>(Click legend to toggle traces)',
        showlegend = True,
        geo = dict(
            scope = 'usa',
            landcolor = 'rgb(219, 219, 219)',
        )
    )

for i in range(len(limits)):
    lim = limits[i]
    Geographics_sub = Geographics[lim[0]:lim[1]]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        lon = Geographics_sub['Longitude'],
        lat = Geographics_sub['Latitude'],
        text = Geographics_sub['text'],
        marker = dict(
            size = Geographics_sub['2019 Population']/scale,
            color = colors[i],
            line_color = 'rgb(40,40,40)',
            line_width = 0.5,
            sizemode = 'area'
        ),
        name = '{0} - {1}'.format(lim[0],lim[1])))

fig.show()
```

Comment: I'm still getting an empty map :/